# Is there a pythonic way to grab the total amount of variables within lists inside a dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7

I have a dictionary where each key has a list (vector) of items:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict = defaultdict(list)
dict[133] = [2,4,64,312]
dict[4] = [2,3,5,12,45,32]
dict[54] = [12,2,443,223]

def getTotalVectorItems(items):
  total = 0
  for v in items.values():
    total += len(v)
  return total

print getTotalVectorItems(dict)
```

This will print:

```
14 # number of items in the 3 dict keys.
```

Is there an easier more pythonic way other than creating this "getTotalVectorItems" function? I feel like there is a quick way to do this already.

Comment: `sum(map(len,dic.values()))`, don't use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: Is there a reason (maybe in code you omitted) that you're using a `defaultdict` here?  Your code would work equally well with `d = {}; d[133] = [2,4,64,312]`, etc.

Comment: Or, better yet: `d = {133: [2, 4, 64, 312], 4: [2, 3, 5, 12, 45, 32], 54: [12, 2, 443, 223]}` - this isn't Java, we have dict literals.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary sorry bout that, my pseudocode was badly written. I'll give your code a shot. I'm using defaultdict because it's the only way to use lists as the value of the dict keys (or so I was told).

Comment: @lattyware oh thanks I didn't realize I can do that.

Comment: Particularly, I use defaultdict because I'm using an array to FILL the integers from a large file, so I didn't want to add a "default" value if statement kind of thing. I guess I could have just used a dict for this pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print sum(map(len,dic.itervalues()))
```

Comment: { 1: 000576, 2: 000405; 1: 000942, 2: 000622; 1: 000655, 2: 000442; 1: 000520, 2: 000436; 1: 000594, 2: 000442; }  Your method (2) seems faster than Lattyware's method.

Comment: @Dexter Thank you. In Python 2, if you use ``imap`` it will certainly be even faster, but I didn't put it in my answer because it needs to be imported. In Python 3, ``map`` is already a generator (or iterator, I never remind which one) - Also, the use of ``itervalues()`` makes faster than use of ``items.values()`` that creates a new object.

Comment: Oh cool, I shall try this immediately. Yeah I won't be using Python 3 for a while, but good to know.

Comment: I don't know why but there doesn't seem to be much speed difference between imap and map. Sometimes one looks faster than the other, other times, the exact opposite (bear in mind I'm not including import time). Ironically using lambda with this stuff sometimes increases speed (rather than calling 3 functions 4 times, you call 1 function 4 times). But it looks like you are right mostly: http://i.imgur.com/VYYfkG5.png

Comment: @Dexter I'm perplexed by what you say. I was so much convinced that ``imap`` would be faster that I wrote "certainly" though hesitating with "probably". I would like to understand while there isn't at least a litle improvement of the speed.

Comment: @Dexter I wonder why lambda would diminish execution time. Timing is a delicate thing, I don't know how you do it. Personally, I let drop ``timeit`` , I use only ``time.clock``. BUT I do many executions, and look the fastest one, because the minimal time of execution (set aside manifestly aberrant values) of a code is the more significant: not my idea, I read it, and that's logical: the minimal time gives the most accurate measure of the speed capacity of a program, added delays being only due to perturbations from the computer.

Comment: I would argue that sacrificing readability for speed is a bad idea unless you have a proven bottleneck. And using `timeit` is always better than doing it manually - it's designed to try and get more reliable results.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure, I just took averages of basic time.clock() deltas. I'm sure you guys can perform more accurate tests. I couldn't figure out why imap is not faster in performance either.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for [the `sum()` built-in](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with a [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
sum(len(v) for v in items.values())
```

The `sum()` function totals the values of the given iterator, and the generator expression yields the length of each value in the lists.

Note that calling lists vectors is probably confusing to most Python programmers, unless you are using the term vector in the context of the domain of the problem.

Comment: Yes but I saying "I want a dict with list values" sounds weird. It's hard to make the distinction between the noun/verb list and the special structure list in python. Thanks I will try both answers in my code and see which is faster.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer but my test revealed the other "map" method seems faster for large dictionaries. Both are correct though.